# A closed form for a summation to find?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, summation

I start as introduction with the well known formula for summing up natural numbers

$\sum _{k=1}^n k$= $\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)$ : formula from Gauss

proving this by induction
$\sum _{k=1}^{n+1} k=\sum _{k=1}^n k+(n+1)$ = $\frac{1}{2} (n+2) (n+1)$(QED)

Another formulation as check
$\text{Assuming}\left[n\geq 1,\text{FullSimplify}\left[\sum _{k=1}^{n+1} k=\sum _{k=1}^n k+(n+1)\right]\right]$ = True

`Assuming[n >= 1, FullSimplify[Sum[k, {k, 1, n + 1}] ==  Sum[k, {k, 1, n}] + (n + 1)]`

$\sum _{k=1}^{n+1} k=\sum _{k=1}^n k+(n+1)$ (summing  up natural numbers)(1,2,3,..n-1, n, **n+1**,..)

`Simplify[Sum[k, {k, 1, n + 1}] == Sum[k, {k, 1, n}] + (n + 1)]`

Now i go to a more difficult expression..

`((-1)^i*(1 - i + k)^(4 + 2*k))/(i!*(2 - i + 2*k)!) =  ((k + 2)*(2*k + 3)*(k + 1))/12`

How can prove this by induction ..by using the idea of the simpler example ?

Comment: The LHS of the second expression that you want to prove has an $i$ and $k$. Is $i$ summed over a domain?

Comment: (1) The equation `((-1)^i*(1 - i + k)^(4 + 2*k))/(i!*(2 - i + 2*k)!) = ((k + 2)*(2*k + 3)*(k + 1))/12` should be written with a `==`, not a `=`, and it's false.  Perhaps a `Sum` or two is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, yes, in the second expression the mathematical formulation has to be properly written in the OP. The sum over $i$ goes from $0$ to $k$, in order for the expression to makes sense. I demonstrate below.

The expression we want to obtain:

```
exp2 = ((k + 2)*(2*k + 3)*(k + 1))/12
```

Do some values

```
Table[exp2, {k, 0, 10}]
```

which yields

> `{1/2, 5/2, 7, 15, 55/2, 91/2, 70, 102, 285/2, 385/2, 253}`

So, now we go back to the LHS and we have the following values

```
Table[With[{k = xx}, 
  Sum[((-1)^i*(1 - i + k)^(4 + 2*k))/(i!*(2 - i + 2*k)!), {i, 0, 
    k}]], {xx, 0, 10}]
```

which gives

> `{1/2, 5/2, 7, 15, 55/2, 91/2, 70, 102, 285/2, 385/2, 253}`

which is obviously the right thing to do.

To get the analytic formula

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1/2, 5/2, 7, 15, 55/2, 91/2, 70, 102, 285/2, 
    385/2, 253}, k] /. k -> k + 1 // FullSimplify
```

which returns

> `1/12 (1 + k) (2 + k) (3 + 2 k)`

and now we are happy.

Comment: thanks I corrected the sum notation. The sum over  goes from 0 to .
Trying to solve the sum using the induction steps also seems like a challenge to me.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Hopefully the answer is clear!

Comment: Have to study the answer first.
I do see at the end of the answer a sequence of numbers, from which a general expression in k is derived.

Comment: You use the expression of the $i$-sum in order to generate data. You use the data obtained to derive a closed-form answer via `FindSequenceFunction`. You check the answer of `FindSequenceFunction` against the expected answer. That's all there is to it to be honest.

Comment: Can be used your calculation as check, if you want to derive the expression by manual induction ( has a educational value)

Comment: @janhardo  No no. Maybe I confused you. Start reading my answer from "So, now we go back to the LHS and we have the following values" onward, and you will realize that it is a complete proof. You manage to get the correct closed-form $k$-formula without knowing it and without using the previous stuff. It's not a check in my opinion since I can derive it.

Comment: @janhardo I just presented the first part, because I wrote my answer before you edited the OP and gave the summation over $i$ in order to demonstrate the validity of what I did.

Comment: But your proof has base 10 numbers , or do i miss something?

Comment: you get an answer with the first 11 elements -from 0 to 10. you can use the answer you get a prediction for next, higher terms. this is the basic principle of proof by induction.

Comment: You get a answer from MMA now, but if want to solve this by hand, you must prove this for all natural numbers

Comment: @janhardo but this is a site for a Mathematica derivation. This is what I provided. For a derivation by hand, perhaps it's more appropriate to ask on the Mathematics site.

Comment: @ DiSp0sablE_H3r0, i am complete satisfied with  your answer , thanks for that!.
Its "Complete induction" and the fun is trying to do it with MMA

Comment: @janhardo glad I helped :-)